# To to remove html tag to get text

Tags: javascript, python

I have text like this:

```
text = 
<option value="tfa_4472" id="tfa_4472" class="">helo 1</option>
<option value="tfa_4473" id="tfa_4473" class="">helo 2</option>
<option value="tfa_4474" id="tfa_4474" class="">helo 3</option>
<option value="tfa_4475" id="tfa_4475" class="">helo 4</option>
<option value="tfa_4476" id="tfa_4476" class="">helo 5</option>
```

### i want get result like this:
my_list = get_text(text)

helo 1
helo 2
helo 3
helo 4
helo 5

Thank you

To to remove html tag to get text

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, the example code is not JavaScript nor Python. Which language are you actually using and where is this code run?

Comment: I agree with @Teemu. This is not Python nor JavaScrip.

Comment: I iunderstan that the "lenguage" ist just "html" and he want the solution in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


myhtml = """<option value="tfa_4472" id="tfa_4472" class="">helo 1</option>
<option value="tfa_4473" id="tfa_4473" class="">helo 2</option>
<option value="tfa_4474" id="tfa_4474" class="">helo 3</option>
<option value="tfa_4475" id="tfa_4475" class="">helo 4</option>
<option value="tfa_4476" id="tfa_4476" class="">helo 5</option>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml, 'html.parser')

my_text = []
for text_tag in  soup.find_all("option", {'class': ''}):
    my_text.append(text_tag.getText())
```

my_text
['helo 1', 'helo 2', 'helo 3', 'helo 4', 'helo 5']

Comment: you can make it shorter - `my_text = [value.get_text() for value in soup.find_all("option")]`

Comment: you are right with the list compresion.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can try to select the option tags with queryselectorall and get the text with innerText by looping over the nodes and appending to myList.

```
$mylist = []
$nodes = document.querySelectorAll('option')

$nodes.forEach($node => {
    $mylist += $node.innerText
});

console.log($mylist)
```